# Daily data shows seasonality when averaged across month. How to adjust on a daily basis?

Tags: time-series, poisson-distribution, autocorrelation, poisson-regression, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have match data across multiple years. I've collected the data in the form `Date  Total Points Scored`

Now here are some issues:

(i) since this is match data, it *does not cover every day*- only the dates when matches were held. Moreover, *multiple matches could be held on the same day*.

(ii) Moreover, each match consists of different teams. This means a simple acf test isn't necessarily useful since the previous entries might be matches b/w entirely different teams for instance.

But there was seasonality to be discovered, which I did by calculating **average number of total points per month**. That is, for every month, I calculated the average of `Total Points Scored` for all matches that took place in that month.

This gave me monthly data and it was very easy to uncover seasonality from this. Take a look:

[image]

The above image shows overall data, trend, seasonality and noise respectively. Again, keep in mind this is not the raw data as is, but the monthly average of the data. When I plot the daily data as is (by taking the averages of points scored per day to deal with multiple entries on the same day), it's a total mess:

[image]

Here I set the period to the average number of days matches are played per year. As you can see, it's very noisy. The seasonality seems to just focus on the gaps between the years and the 'seasonal trends' are just all the games played per year.

So basically, **I have only been able to capture seasonality using monthly averages.** Is there a way to capture it on a daily basis, given all the quirks of this data?

**Moreover**, I was using Poisson regression w/ MLE to model total goals scored. This is a General Linear Model and thus doesn't take into account seasonal trends above.

**How could I incorporate monthly average seasonal trends into Poisson Regression?**

The obvious answer is some form of Poisson autoregression but again, since it is difficult to capture the seasonality in the daily data, it is difficult to know how many lag factors I need.

Can I subtract avg seasonality for the data, apply Poisson regression on the seasonal adjusted data and then add seasonality back again? Doesn't seem very sound, statistically speaking.

Comment: (1) Without seeing the vertical axes, there is no way of telling how strong the monthly seasonality is. It could well be minuscule. After all, an STL decomposition plot expands each component vertically to fill the available space - so components that happen on completely different scales can look comparable in plots. (2) What are you trying to do by incorporating seasonality into a model? Are you trying to predict, or something else?

Comment: That's my bad on (1)- I pulled bad images. The monthly seasonality is significant enough- roughly about $0.5$ difference in the y-axis (this is soccer and most games have $\leq 2$ goals so it's significant. 

(2) Yes I'm trying to predict.